# best way to handle only hours and minutes in Java

Tags: java, time

I have an application that manages objects where each object is associated with a class and have the order to execute commands at certain times of day, for example once at 9am, another at 2pm. My question is: what is the best way to handle only times in java? I am using the Calendar and Time classes but I must give obligatorily year, month, day, which for me are unusable data. My account manipulate events schedules through an object that handles dates is not optimal, then as I can do it?

Comment: If you don't like existing `Calendar` or `Date` classes, you're always welcome to write your own class `Time` that would do exactly what you need.

Comment: I think Java 8 has a concept of "time" only class...

Answer (score 13):

## Joda-Time

Use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), in particular [LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(12, 20);
```

## java.time

Similarly, the java.time package built into Java 8 also offers a `LocalTime` class.

Comment: Or if you're using Java 8, use the [`java.time.LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

very good response naumcho but unfortunately I can not use that version of java. Finally I ended up creating my own class:

```
public class Tiempo {
    public Integer hora;
    public Integer minuto;
    public Integer segundo;

    public Tiempo(){}

    public Tiempo(String tiempo){
        this.parse(tiempo);
    }

    /**
     * Convierte un tiempo de tipo String a formato Tiempo
     * @param tiempo Tiempo en formato HH:mm:ss (24 horas)
     * @return Retorna true si fué convertido correctamente, en caso contrario retorna false.
     */
    public Boolean parse(String tiempo){
        try{

            this.hora = Integer.parseInt(tiempo.split(":")[0]);
            this.minuto = Integer.parseInt(tiempo.split(":")[1]);
            this.segundo = Integer.parseInt(tiempo.split(":")[2]);

            Boolean valido = (
                (this.hora >= 0) &&
                (this.hora <= 23) &&
                (this.minuto >= 0) &&
                (this.minuto <= 59) &&
                (this.segundo >= 0) &&
                (this.segundo <= 59)
            );

            if(valido){
                return true;

            }else{
                this.hora = null;
                this.minuto = null;
                this.segundo = null;

                return false;
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            this.hora = null;
            this.minuto = null;
            this.segundo = null;

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param a Tiempo a comparar
     * @param b Tiempo a comparar
     * @return Retorna un número negativo si a es menor que b, retorna 0 si son iguales, retorna un número positivo si a es mayor que b, retorna null si uno de ambos tiempos era nulo
     */
    static public Integer comparar(Tiempo a, Tiempo b){

        if((a == null) || (b == null)){
            return null;
        }

        if(a.hora < b.hora) {
            return -1;

        }else if(a.hora == b.hora){

            if(a.minuto < b.minuto){
                return -2;

            }else if(a.minuto == b.minuto){

                if(a.segundo < b.segundo){
                    return -3;

                }else if(a.segundo == b.segundo){

                    return 0;

                }else if(a.segundo > b.segundo){
                    return 3;
                }

            }else if(a.minuto > b.minuto){
                return 2;
            }

        }else if(a.hora > b.hora){
            return 1;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
Tiempo a = new Tiempo("09:10:05");
Tiempo b = new Tiempo("15:08:31");

if(Tiempo.compare(a, b) < 0){
 // a < b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something really powerful out there called
[Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) it provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes.

Comment: naumcho's answer already mentions Joda Time. You don't need to repeat the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which orders Calendar or Time classes only by the fields you desire:

```java
class HourMinuteComparator implements Comparator<Calendar> {
  public int compare(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
    int hour1 = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int hour2 = c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (hour1 == hour2) {
      int minute1 = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int minute2 = c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      return minute2 - minute1;
    } else {
      return hour2 - hour1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good but when you set the hours of the calendar object anyway you must set the year, month and day, your example only obtains and compares but could not establish and while you are using a data object dead.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for scheduling operations would be [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j)

Comment: That's when establishing the execution, but to save the value in the object before processing the cron can not use this library.